# Add service reference creates client without methods

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2012, wsdl, windows-store-apps, portable-class-library

Hi when I trie to create a client for wsdl service (this one: http://webapi.aukro.cz/uploader.php?wsdl) the "add service reference" in VS 2012 creates a client that has no methods in it.

Ive tried to create a test connection on this service in the wcftestclient app and most of the generated methods are marked as errors with message "This opertion is not supported in wcftestclient because it uses type xy", where xy is some type from the service.

Edit: Ive been trying to do this in a windows store app... 
Edit2: Ive just tried to add reference in a "windows class library" project at it works without any problems. "Portable class library" project is no go so far.

Any ideas?

Comment: Look in the Output window after you do the "Add Service Reference". There may be errors listed there. Also, look at the reference.cs file that it generated to see if the comments refer to any errors. Finally, try using svcutil.exe on the wsdl and look for errors.

Comment: Can you make sure you have these patches installed on your machine and try? Win8 / Win2012 : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2750149
Downlevel OS : support.microsoft.com/kb/2750147. I cannot reproduce this problem.

Comment: I cannot install neather of those updates (W8x64). Ive checked Installed Updates for 2750149  and 2750147 - found none.

Comment: What's your OS? And is there any error messages that you get while installing the updates? And as @JohnSaunders mentioned can you check what errors you get on the errors tab. For example check this blog post : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/praburaj/archive/2012/08/23/add-service-reference-adding-empty-reference-cs-in-mvc-4-projects-of-vs-2012.aspx to see how to work around a sample error like this.

Comment: "Custom tool warning: Contract 'AllegroWebApiPortType' is not compatible with Windows Store apps because it contains one or more operations with SOAP Encoding (use='encoded'). Only the non-encoded operations will be generated." That kinda explains it..

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve a similar problem by doing the following:

> Check your Service Reference. Right-click and "Configure Service
>   Reference". Uncheck "Reuse types in referenced assemblies" and let it
>   rebuild the proxies.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33422442/4695159