# Service reference is not creating methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, soap

I'm trying to add a service reference to a SOAP web service into my ASP.NET MVC application so I'm able to consume the web service from here.

The problem is, that the service reference isn't creating any class or method I can use from my regular app, it's only defining two interfaces and a lot of data types.

Maybe I'm mistaken, but as I'm understanding it, the service reference should create a class that I'd be able to use to call the different methods on the service. Then is my job to translate my business model data to the data types of the web service so I can send parameters to methods and work with their responses.

Am I doing it wrong and should use a different approach to consume external SOAP web services?

Comment: Have you tried adding it as a `Web reference`? Try doing it as: Add service reference\Advanced\Add Web reference. I had similar issue and it helped me.

Comment: Doing so creates some delegates instead of the interfaces. Those delegates include methods to invoke... I'll play a bit with them and see what can I do with them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check your Service Reference. Right-click and "Configure Service Reference". Uncheck "Reuse types in referenced assemblies" and let it rebuild the proxies.

In my case I created a Service Reference to my WCF service called "Example". This creates a namespace `WebApplication1.Example`.

My WCF service is simply called `Service1` which is an implementation of `IService1`, which has the 2 default operations and an `Add` that I added for funsies.

Once the Service Reference is there, I have a `using WebApplication1.Example;` and then in C#, `var client = new Service1Client();`. Note that the convention appends "-Client" to my service name, which makes sense, as it's a proxy to the actual service.

From there it's just `var x = client.Add(5, 6);`

BTW, you may not want a Web Reference. While it may "just work", it's not even close to being the same thing as a Service Reference. [Web Reference vs. Service Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158106/web-reference-vs-service-reference)

HTH!

Comment: Absolutely! After unchecking and updating, the client class appeared, it worked like a charm! Thank you.

Comment: Click Advanced e Add Web Reference. Solved to me!